# Finding WWII Royal Fleet Auxiliary (RFA) Records?

Tags: military-records, united-kingdom, world-war-2

Are there any records for the Royal Fleet Auxiliary?

Albert George Adcock was in the RFA at Chatham about 1934 he was posted to Hong Kong and was captain of the Navy tug "Enticer". He was drowned at sea when the tug was sunk during a typhoon, 21st December 1946, and is buried in Hong Kong. I have not been able to find any information about his WWII service.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Genealogy.Stackexchange! I presume you mean 1934 and not 1834 and have edited accordingly -- please undo the edit if I'm wrong. Have you reviewed the answers at http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3530/104 to see if there's any relevance. However, I've not been able to find Albert George at either of the online sites mentioned.

Comment: I assume you've seen: http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ww2peopleswar/stories/63/a5884563.shtml

Answer (score 4):

According to "*Tracing Your Naval Ancestors*" (by Simon Fowler, Pen & Sword, 2011) from 1921, officers on RFA ships were ranked as Merchant Navy officers. Before that most were Royal Naval Reserve officers. For merchant navy officers, you should start with The National Archives guide "[Looking for records of an officer in the Merchant Navy](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/records/looking-for-person/officermerchantnavy.htm)".

Not a lot of help, I'm afraid, but at least this seems to indicate which "Navy" he was in (Merchant, rather than Royal).

Answer (score 0):

I bought my father's RFA History about 10 yrs ago but have lost them he was McDonald Dall dob 1.2.23 Edinburgh served on Eddyfirth when I was born 25.2.54
Ralph Dall

Answer (score -1):

The fastest and most straightforward way to obtain the information required by you on your father Albert George Adcock, might very well be to go to the Royal Fleet Auxiliary facebook page, which is administered by RN Public Relations and to ask them, as his next of kin, for the information required by you and also, if required by you, a full copy of Service Record, as his next of kin, from which to extend the information already know to you and from which to then extend back your family line, if you require to do so. However I am unsure, if his service record, would have been destroyed as he died in service or not.

Comment: Do you mean this page? https://www.facebook.com/RoyalFleetAuxiliary/ Answers with sources/links are those which I think have the most value here.  I think anything that means the viewer of a question has to go elsewhere to assemble a complete answer is less useful than it could be.